# Как сделать правильно консольное приложение с кодировкой UTF-8

Tags: c++

Дело в том что если создать файл с кодировкой UTF-8 то при запуски в консоли не пишется русский язык.
Даже если вы добавите

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
system("chcp 1251");

std::cout <<  (LC_ALL,"Русский текст") << "\n ";
```

Это не помогает, единственно это вернуть кодировку файла в Windows 1251

Если ли хоть какое то решение что бы не менять кодировку файла и отображать русский текст в консоли?

Comment: Эх, вопрос закрылся, однако там по-факту нет совета именно про кодировку utf-8. При некотором желании консоль можно переключить на codepage 65001.

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос закрыли фиг знает зачем, ответа там нету